# Access C/C++ lib from a multiplatform kotlin project

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

For the first time, I'm using Android Studio to build a multiplatform project. I have created an Android app module that uses the multiplatform lib on Android.
I have also used XCode to build an iOS app that uses the multiplatform lib on iOS.
Everything works fine and I'm able to use the `expect fun` that is implemented by different `actual fun` for Android and iOS.

I have also created a library in C++ that exposes a C interface.

```
#ifndef PINGLIB_LIBRARY_H
#define PINGLIB_LIBRARY_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    long long elapsed;
} PingInfo;

typedef void (*PingCallback)(PingInfo pingInfo);
typedef struct
{
    PingCallback pingUpdate;
} PingObserver;

void* ping(const char * url, const PingCallback *pingCallback);
void subscribe(void* pingOperation);
void unsubscribe(void* pingOperation);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //PINGLIB_LIBRARY_H
```

I use CLion to build the C++ code.
I have created a `.def` file that I use to build the library using `cinterop`.

```
package = com.exercise.pinglib
headers = PingLibrary.h
linkerOpts.linux = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
compilerOpts = -std=c99 -I/Users/username/myproject/ping/ping/header
staticLibraries = libping.a
libraryPaths = /opt/local/lib /Users/username/myproject/ping/cmake-build-debug
```

`libping.a` is the library created building the C++ code. It is created in the folder `/Users/username/myproject/ping/cmake-build-debug`

When I run the command `cinterop -def ping.def -o ping`, it creates the klib file and a folder containing a `manifest.properties` file a `natives` subfolder containing a `cstubs.bc` file and a `kotlin` subfolder with a `.kt` file.

```
ping.klib
-ping-build
    manifest.properties
    -natives
        cstubs.bc
    -kotlin
        -com
            -exercise
                -pinglib
                    pinglib.kt
```

How can I use the library created by `cinterop` in my kotlin-multiplatform project?

I have found different ways to import it but I did not find any complete description of how to do it.
[Here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/1828) they say that I can use something like:

```
    implementation files("ping.klib")
```

I did it for the iOS project but I still don't know how to access the kotlin classes neither on Android nor on iOS.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
kotlin {
    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith('iphoneos') ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64
        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'ios') {
            binaries {
                framework('shared')
            }
        }
        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
    }
    sourceSets {
        // for common code
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
        }
        iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation files("ping.klib")
        }
    }
}
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}

task packForXCode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'
    final def framework = kotlin.targets.ios.binaries.getFramework("shared", mode)
    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn framework.linkTask
    from { framework.outputFile.parentFile }
    into frameworkDir
    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}
tasks.build.dependsOn packForXCode
```

**EDIT**
I have changed the question because, initially, I thought that `cinterop` was not creating the klib library but it was just a mistake: I was looking in the `ping-build` folder but the file is outside that folder. So I resolved half of the question.

**EDIT2**
I have added the `build.script`

Comment: Hello, @kingston! Can you extend the question with an example of `cinterop` call? At first sight, it seems like you have set the `-Xnopack=true` here, so you got a `ping-build`, but no `ping.klib`.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I do not add that flag so I guess that by default it is false. I added the command in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad to see that everything is fine with the KLIB, now about the library use. 
First of all, I have to mention that this library can be utilized only by Kotlin/Native compiler, meaning it will be available for some targets(see list [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#supported-platforms)). Then, if you're going to include C library use into an MPP project, it is always better to produce bindings via the Gradle script. It can be done inside of a  target, see [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#cinterop-support) doc for example. For your iOS target it should be like:

```
kotlin {
    iosX64 {  // Replace with a target you need.
        compilations.getByName("main") {
            val ping by cinterops.creating {
                defFile(project.file("ping.def"))
                packageName("c.ping")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet will add cinterop task to your Gradle, and provide module to include like `import c.ping.*` inside of the corresponding Kotlin files.

Comment: do you know any general reasons why the corresponding Kotlin files wouldn't be able to see the `c.ping.*` (as in my case) ? I'm using target `androidNativeArm64` in `kotlin { ... }` block of the shared Gradle file.

Comment: to Hi, @Pixel! In general, there are two possible problems - the `cinterop` tool did not create correct bindings, or the IDE cannot add them as a dependency, or resolve symbols. For the first problem, please check if the bindings are correct. They should be located in the `build/classes/kotlin/androidNativeArm64/main/` file, after the `cinteropMainAndroidNativeArm64` task execution. If the KLIB is there, you should be able to check its contents using `klib contents <KLIB_NAME>` CLI command. The `klib` executable should be located at the `~/.konan/kotlin-native-<version>/bin/klib`.

Comment: Please perform those steps and reach me with the results.

Comment: hey there, thanks for replying. Yes the `.klib` is there. and `klib contents` gives `package c.mylib {
    @CCall(id = "knifunptr_c_mylib0_hello") external fun hello(): Int
}`. But I'm not sure about your last point. I can't seem to find any `.kexe` files in the `~/.konan` directory or its subfolders, e.g. I did `find . -name "*.kexe"` and nothing showed up ! So I guess that is the problem? Would you know how I might go about fixing that? (ps my full steps can be read in my SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851318/kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-cant-find-klib-package)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the `klib` utility can be found in this folder: `~/.konan/kotlin-native-<version>/bin/klib`. If it works correctly without specifying the full path - nice!

Comment: So, the problem is that you have this `external fun hello()` in the KLIB, but cannot use it from the Kotlin code. Does it mean the code importing this function is not building, or the problem is about the red lines in the IDE?

Comment: I'll take a look. I don't think it's the red lines because the project builds and runs on the Android device (and there's this known bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838225/expected-class-has-no-actual-declaration)